# Eclipse Product Launch

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I have created RCP-Product with plugins and when I try to launch the application I am getting below error
[image]

Can anyone help me out to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the plug-in that provides the EventAdmin service.

This service is provided by the `org.eclipse.equinox.event` plug-in in all versions of Eclipse from 4.7 to 4.17